# Linear Algebra (trace): How to pull out $X^T[...]X$?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

In fallowing equation - (1) $tr(X^TA^TAX+X^TLX)$  equals to $tr(X^T[A^TA+L]X)$.
My question is how about in the following equation
(2) $tr(X^TA^TAX+X^TXL)$, can we pull out $tr(X^T[...]X)$ like first equation (1)?
Any suggestions are welcome,

Comment: If $L$ and $X$ commute, then that's the case. See Math.SO for [When is matrix multiplication commutative?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170241/when-is-matrix-multiplication-commutative)

Comment: For 1 x 1 matrices you always can, for 2 x 2 matrices you can create counterexamples.  Very useful to work out a counterexample, will help you understand matrix multiplication better.

Comment: Why does the word "trace" appear in your title? While its *not* in general the case that you can pull the $X$ out on the right side in (2), *if you're actually dealing with the trace*, you should make certain to include that in the expressions in the body of your post, since there's important [results with the trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29#Trace_of_a_product) you can use: $\text{tr}(AB)=\text{tr}(BA)$

Comment: @Glen_b, sorry for about that, actually all notations are with the trace. I checked your link and still cannot solve it. Particularly, we have 3 matrices $tr(X^TXL)$, so I think we cannot apply it $tr(AB) = tr(BA)$, and I checked using MATLAB numerical toolbox.

Comment: It's not clear what kind of formula you would hope to find. If $X$ is an $n\times p$ matrix, then $L$ must be $p\times p$ and what goes inside the brackets has to be $n\times n$: the dimensions don't match.

Comment: @Whuber, simply in Eq(1) we can pull out $X^t[...]X$, how about in the second Eq(2)? Is it possible or not?

Comment: Indeed, it's important to be clear about dimensions of all the objects; if the dimensions of X and L aren't suitable (in effect, if X and L aren't square), you can't do this -- it doesn't make sense to consider swapping the order of anything if the matrices aren't [conformable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformable_matrix). In Equation 1, the X is at the end of both expressions, so nothing is swapped. You're just using the distributive law.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some properties about matrix and traces. We assume in what follows that all matrices are square.

(i) $\text{tr}(AB) = \text{tr}(BA)$

(ii) $\text{tr}(A+B) = \text{tr}(B+A)$

(iii) $(AB)C = A(BC)$

(iv) $\text{tr}(A^t) = \text{tr}(A)$

(v) $(AB)^t = B^t A^t$

**Fake Proposition:** $\text{tr}(ABC) = \text{tr}(BAC) = \text{tr}(CBA) = ... $ (any permutation)

**Proof:** Actually this is false. See this, 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixTrace.html

Now to return to your specific problem.

$\text{tr} (X^tA^tAX + X^tXL) = \text{tr} (X^tA^tAX) + \text{tr} (X^tXL) $ by (ii)

Look at the second summand, then use (iv)

$\text{tr} (X^tXL) = \text{tr} (X^tXL)^t= \text{tr} (L^t X^t X) $

Therefore, we are left with,

$\text{tr} (X^tA^tAX) + \text{tr} (L^t X^t X) $

If the Proposition was true,

$\text{tr} (L^t X^t X) = \text{tr} (X^t L^t X)$

Hence,

$$\text{tr} (X^tA^tAX) + \text{tr} (X^t L^t X) = \text{tr}[ X^t(A^tA + L^t) X]$$

But unfortunately, I do not think you can take that one last step to put it into the form you would like.